# Proper error handling in node using try catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

Im new to javascript programming and i am required to make a web app. Node.js will be used as the js runtime environment. In order to minimize the amount of time needed for debugging as the app develops I would like to implement a robust error handling scheme. However, due to my limited background I am not sure if what I am implementing is best practise or if it is even adequate. So any feedback will be accepted.

The function is asynchronous and will use catch to detect if any errors occurred while operating. A try-catch statement will be used to catch any errors. This was done in order to allow for individual error identification from the functions. My aim is to propagate the errors up to the calling function that will handle it in the highest level catch statement (in my case where it is logged *this will change eventually). Any feedback?

```js
create: async function(req, res) {
  let data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  let result;
  let request_body;
  let sub_networks_lora;
  try {
    request_body = sub_network_api_request_data(data, 1);
    result = await lora_app_server.create_applications(request_body)
      .catch(err => {
        //Error updating application on lora app server
        throw err;
      });
    await db_sub_networks.create_sub_network(result.data.id, data.sub_network_name, data.network_id)
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
        //Error creating sub network in database 
      });
    sub_networks_lora = await get_sub_networks()
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
        //Error getting networks from lora app server
      })
    sub_networks_lora = JSON.stringify(sub_networks_lora);
    res.status(200).send({
      sub_networks_lora
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } finally {}
}
```

Comment: If your code is currently working then your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it deals with code reviews. Otherwise if you have an actual problem with your current code you need to state that problem.

Comment: I feel that the error should be sent in the response as well like   
    res.status(400).send(err);    And also json.parse() would look better in the try{}

Comment: So conceptually nothing is wrong with the code? @SachinS.